# How to swap data stored in a member of a structure (a node) in C, when the member itself is a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, nodes

I'm trying to build a linked list in C, which is made up of nodes I've defined as follows:

```
struct Node {
    void *nodeData;
    struct Node *next;
};
```

My goal is to sort the list without swapping the nodes themselves but by instead swapping the data they hold. If for example, I pass in the list head to a function like `void func(*listHead)`, I've set up a current pointer and a trail pointer like so:

```
struct Node *temp;
struct Node *current = listHead;
struct Node *trail = current->next;
```

And when I try to swap the data, I do:

```
temp->nodeData = trail->nodeData;
trail->nodeData = current->nodeData;
current->nodeData = temp->nodeData;
```

But this ends up overriding the data of all the nodes with whatever was in trail's nodeData member. If I'm understanding this correctly, it's because I'm making all the pointers point to the same thing (an address?) and not actually swapping the values stored in nodeData. How can I get around this?

Comment: [mcve] please....

Comment: If you want to swap the data, then your temporary should be of type nodedata, but you need to know how large it is. Void* isn't good enough.

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, I can't be sure, but it looks like maybe you haven't allocated any memory for what `temp` actually points to! If so, then when you do `temp->nodeData = trail->nodeData` you are accessing some random area of memory, and this will cause **undefined behaviour**.

Comment: Use a `struct` as temp, not pointer.  `struct Node *temp;` --> `struct Node temp;`

Comment: @AdrianMole This was exactly the problem. Temp was not pointing anywhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All pointers need to point somewhere meaningful before they are used. Pointers to struct are no exception. You can't use `struct Node *temp;` since it doesn't point anywhere. Instead do:

```
void* tmp = trail->nodeData;
trail->nodeData = current->nodeData;
current->nodeData = tmp;
```